# How to get the share value number. Should use css or js

Tags: javascript, php, css

How to get the share value number. Should use css or javascript :

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by share value number?

Comment: @MohammedShareefC i want use value share number for my website

Comment: You mean social sharing widgets. Google "Share It"

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you talk more specifically?

Comment: @JaromandaX 
I have tried but it's failed

Answer (score 0):

That's a Facebook widget. You can read how to implement it on [Social Plugins - Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button).

The widget is what brings the share functionality and number of re-shares automatically, depending on how you configure it.

If you do not want the whole button as your screenshot, but only the number of shares, you could make call to:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://stackoverflow.com
```

It returns a JSON with both comment count and share count.

See [this git page](https://gist.github.com/jonathanmoore/2640302#facebook) for other Share numbers.

Comment: configure button share facebook not get only value number

Comment: The one you took a screenshot of is exactly that Share button! Editing and adding how to get only number of shares, but I feel the Q was not clear.